# Resolve file paths relatively to a .iss file included from another folder

Tags: inno-setup

I am using the `#include` preprocessor directive to include other `.iss` files that contain separate components of my drivers installation.

```
[Files]
#include "subfolder\issComponent.iss"
```

and `issComponent.iss` performs an installation of a driver from its own relative path.

```
[Files]
Source: "Driver\Driver.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Driver.exe";
```

When I try to build the main/calling script, the relative path to `Driver.exe` do not work due to the relative pathing being referenced from the location of the main/calling script.

The path from the `issComponent.iss` resolves to

```
.\Driver\Driver.exe
```

instead of

```
.\subfolder\Driver\Driver.exe
```

since the include statement includes the file statements directly, and does not compile it from its own path. This is what is causing the error. I am wondering if there is a way to correctly use the relative paths in both locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#include` is interpreted by preprocessor. The `[Files]` (and other sections) are interpreted by compiler. Those are separate components which do not know about each other. Just like in C/C++. The preprocessor merges the `issComponent.iss` into the main `.iss` file like this:

```
[Files]
[Files]
Source: "Driver\Driver.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Driver.exe";
```

And the the compiler won't even know that the lines were originally in a different file, let alone in a different folder.

---

You can make use of some preprocessor capabilities to achieve what you want. For example the `__PATHFILENAME__` [predefined variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars), which resolves to the path to the `.iss` file, where it is referenced.

```
#define PathToSelf ExtractFileDir(__PATHFILENAME__)
Source: "{#PathToSelf}\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

This will result in final `.iss` script like:

```
[Files]
[Files]
Source: "C:\full\path\to\subfolder\Driver\Driver.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Driver.exe";
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for the help!